# my app is rejected by play console with permission error api

Tags: android, flutter, dart, console, playback

app rejected due to permission error

[image: image1]

[image: imag2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

using payu payment gateway
unable understand which payment gateway console asking
ssue found: Invalid or inaccurate Permission Form

Your app uses sensitive permissions that require a Permissions Declaration Form to be properly submitted. Please check that you have accurately submitted the form in the Play console and that you are only using the allowed permission for your declared use case(s).

For additional guidance, please review the documentation on how to request app permissions.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Permissions
About the Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy

Action required: Submit an updated app for review

Here's what to do to help get your app on Google Play:
Make sure to read the applicable policies or requirements listed below:
Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy
Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to address the issue described above. You may also want to check your app's store listing for compliance, if applicable.
Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
If you made changes to your app bundle, store listing, or APK, please sign in to your Play Console and submit the update(s).